# ASP.NET MVC: Stack overflow error when calling Html.RenderPartial()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial

I have a Controller called **ActivationController** with a **LogOn** action, which renders the view LogOn.aspx. 
LogOn.aspx renders a partial view called LogOn.ascx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    LogOn
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Account Activation Step 1 - Log On</h2>

    <p>
        <%Html.RenderPartial("LogOn")<;%>
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

When calling the action i'm getting a "Stack Overflow" exception:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll*

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hello dear kindly please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702746/how-to-include-a-partial-view-inside-a-webform

Answer (score 6):

Don't bother to reply, i found the issue.

The problem was that partial view should have a different name than the view. :P

Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("LogOn")<;%>
```

it should look like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LogOn");%>
```