# How to add .aspx pages to existing MVC 4 project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webforms

I have working ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I want to add to this MVC project 2 `.aspx` pages of another WebForms project. I have several questions:

1. Where should I copy this `.aspx` files and how should I *config* my
   routes?
2. How should I tell this `.aspx` pages to use `~/Shared/_Layout.chtml` as a *master page?*
3. Additionally this *.aspx pages* uses *.ascx controls*. Where should I store them?
4. How should I modify *web.config file?*

I have looked at the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203467/1893261) posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms) question, but they seemed to be outdated. A lot of the links explain how to add MVC to WebForms, but I am looking for all the way around.

Any useful links would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The post from Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx is still valid, it does not matter if you integrate a WebForm application into an MVC or vice versa the steps are the same. Using an Razor template for an .aspx page as master page does not work, it's not not possible to combine them due to the different view engines used.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the comment. So if it is not possible to combine them, is it possible to do it with another approach?

Comment: the simplest way is to have a ASP.NET WebFormViewEngine (.aspx) master page and a Razor template base-layout (.chtml)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*The solution:*

As it turned out, adding **.aspx** pages to the existing **MVC** project is an even easier task to accomplish than adding mvc to .aspx. The most interesting thing for me was to find out that both webforms and MVC, in the scope of one project share **one** runtime on IIS.

*So what I did:*

1. Added **.aspx** pages from another project to the **root** of my **MVC** project
2. Created new **master page** for my **webforms** pages(right click project->add->new item->Master Page)
3. In order to make **Master Page** of WF and **_Layout.chtml** of MVC share the same **Master 'View'** I found [this great article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702746/how-to-include-a-partial-view-inside-a-webform) that allows you to call something similar to **@Html.RenderPartial()** method within **.aspx page**
4. The following code provides information how to implement **RenderPartial** method in WebForms:

   ```
   public class WebFormController : Controller { }

   public static class WebFormMVCUtil
   {

       public static void RenderPartial( string partialName, object model )
       {
           //get a wrapper for the legacy WebForm context
           var httpCtx = new HttpContextWrapper( System.Web.HttpContext.Current );

           //create a mock route that points to the empty controller
           var rt = new RouteData();
           rt.Values.Add( "controller", "WebFormController" );

           //create a controller context for the route and http context
           var ctx = new ControllerContext( 
           new RequestContext( httpCtx, rt ), new WebFormController() );

           //find the partial view using the viewengine
           var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView( ctx, partialName ).View;

           //create a view context and assign the model
           var vctx = new ViewContext( ctx, view, 
               new ViewDataDictionary { Model = model }, 
               new TempDataDictionary() );

           //render the partial view
           view.Render( vctx, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output );
       }

   }
   ```

   Add it to codebehind.cs of your .aspx page. Then you can call it from the webforms like this:

   ```
   <% WebFormMVCUtil.RenderPartial( "ViewName", this.GetModel() ); %>
   ```
5. Since I had only the 'menu' shared among all my pages, I added it to the partial View, then called it in **_Layout.chtml**

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_Menu")
   ```

and in **MasterPage.Master** like this:

```
    <% WebFormMVCUtil.RenderPartial("_Menu", null ); %>
```

That is all there is to it. As a result my **_Layout.chtml** and **MasterPage.Master** use the same shared partial views. And I can acess **.aspx** pages simply by navigating on them.  If you have some issues with routing system, you can add `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");` to your routeConfig in App_Start.

Sources I used:

1. [Combine asp net mvc with webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms)
2. [Mixing Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/)
3. [MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPages](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)
4. [How to include a partial view inside a webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702746/how-to-include-a-partial-view-inside-a-webform)

I hope it will help somebody later on.

Comment: I am stuck on GetModel() in the call from the webform. The error I see is "z.aspx does not contain a definition for 'GetModel' and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'z_aspx' could be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I can't find where GetModel is defined.